# Different versions of Racket

Tags: scheme

A friend helped me install Racket 6.1 on my Ubuntu a long time ago. He did something with `make` I don't know and now I have a Racket folder in my home directory.

Recently I'd like to upgrade Racket to 6.5, so I added Racket ppa to apt-get and then upgrade successfully. However, as I type racket into terminal, it's still version 6.1. Drracket is still 6.1, too.

```
Setting up racket-common (6.5-20160429~trusty) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/racket/config.rktd ...
Setting up racket (6.5-20160429~trusty) ...
xxx@laptop:~$ racket --version
Welcome to Racket v6.1.
```

I opened the `/etc/racket/config.rktd`, it prescribes racket directory as /usr/share/applications. When I opened `/usr/share/applications`, there's an icon of `DrRacket` and clicking on it's 6.1.

What can I do now?

Thank you,

**UPDATE:**
This is before I move the racket folder to Trash

```
chi@laptop:~$ racket --version
Welcome to Racket v6.1.

chi@laptop:~$ which racket
/home/chi/racket/bin/racket

chi@laptop:~$ echo $PATH
/home/chi/racket/bin:/home/chi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

This is after I move it to Trash

```
chi@laptop:~$ racket --version
bash: /home/chi/racket/bin/racket: No such file or directory

chi@laptop:~$ which racket
/usr/bin/racket

chi@laptop:~$ echo $PATH
/home/chi/racket/bin:/home/chi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

If I restore the racket folder from Trash, it's like before.
Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on the command-line invocation first. My guess is that your PATH includes the path of the old installation (the one in your home directory) first. Or perhaps it's just a question of doing a rehash. Here's what I'd suggest:

- Open a new terminal window (one way to make sure that paths are refreshed).
- run `racket --version`, make sure that it's still 6.1.
- run `which racket` to see which version of racket you're running. I'm guessing it'll be one installed in your home directory.
- run `echo $PATH` to see what your PATH looks like. My guess is that the path to the one installed in your home directory will occur before the one installed using the ppa.

*If* everything I've supposed is true, then you can probably solve this by deleting the `racket` directory in your home directory (or, more conservatively, by moving it to `/tmp` so you can get it back if you want).

After removing the racket from your home directory you need to tell your shell (`bash`), that the command has disappeared from previous location, because bash shell remembers location of commands already used.  You can remove this command hash table either by running: `hash -r` or just closing existing shell instances and opening new terminal window.

Comment: I did as you said and include the output of terminal in the edited question. Can you check that? Thank you.

Comment: @linchi I added information about `hash -r` to the answer.